# Querying Oracle through SQL Server linked server and date values

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am trying to reach some data in a legacy Oracle DB that is attached to a SQL Server as a "linked server". I have an Oracle table and one of the columns is of `Date` type. Values in this column can be NULL.

In the query I am building I hope to return either just the "date" portion of the column value or an empty string if the value is NULL.

I am currently trying:

```
  CASE
     WHEN ACCOUNT.DATE_REVOKED IS NULL
     THEN ''
     ELSE CONVERT(DATE, ACCOUNT.DATE_REVOKED)
  END
```

This works for values with actual dates. For NULL values what is returned as "1900/01/01". If I do not use the `CASE` and just return the result of

```
    CONVERT(DATE, ACCOUNT.DATE_REVOKED)
```

I will get the date portion or the text "NULL", at least in SQL Server Management Studio.

What am I missing?

Comment: If your destination date column is of DATE type then it will allow valid date or a NULL value store. You cannot store '' (blank) in DATE data type column. if you want '' blank to be stored in it then you have to change the data type of the column to VARCHAR().

Comment: As @SagarShelke said, if you have a datetime, and write '' (blank) to it, the end result is 1900-01-01.  SQL Server will NOT store a blank in a datetime, but it will store NULL if its nullable.  Yes a varchar would do it, but why... that's just bad practice; it opens you up to bad data, and bad performance, and more headaches when you try to handle the data later.

Answer (score 0):

as the comments have suggested, you cannot use empty string in date column, therefore, why not use this instead:

```
CASE
    WHEN ACCOUNT.DATE_REVOKED IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CONVERT(DATE, ACCOUNT.DATE_REVOKED)
END
```